# Getting absolute filepath from Google Cloud Storage for use with pdf-text-extract

Tags: node.js, pdf, path, google-cloud-storage, filepath

The package `pdf-text-extract` requires an absolute filepath. I need to use this package on files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Is there a way to pass a file from a GCS bucket as an absolute URL?

Here is my code (Node.js):

```js
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const extract = require('pdf-text-extract');

const bucketFile = 'http://bucketname.storage.googleapis.com/fileName.pdf';

extract(bucketFile, 
    (err, pages) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }

        console.log(pages);
    }
);
```

This returns an error:

`Error: pdf-text-extract command failed: I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'D:\Libraries\Documents\pdf-text-extract-bucket\http:\bucketname.storage.googleapis.com\fileName.pdf'`

I've also tried passing this to the extract function:

file = storage.bucket('bucketname').file('fileName.pdf');

The way it works with local files (instead of GCS buckets):

```js
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, tempFileName);  
extract(filePath, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/nisaacson/pdf-text-extract/blob/master/index.js) for the pdf-text-extract, it 's only designed to work on local files (it uses path.resolve() for the filepaths you pass as parameters). Unless you want to change the way this module works, you can just [download the file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs) to your local system:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const options = { destination: destFilename,};
storage.bucket(bucketName).file(srcFilename).download(options);
```

And then you can use it:

```
const localFile = path.join(destFilename, srcFilename);
extract(localFile, 
    (err, pages) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }

        console.log(pages);
    }
);
```

Comment: I guess the question is, is there a way to use google-cloud/storage buckets as if they were local storage?

Comment: As you can read in the [GitHub page](https://github.com/nisaacson/pdf-text-extract): "You will need the pdftotext binary available on your path". Therefore, you need to have your data where your package is.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the filepath from a file on the google cloud storage to open an sqlite database, this is the code I found and used, worked like a charm

```js
// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
const metadata = {
  contentType: contentType,
};
return bucket.file(filePath).download({
  destination: tempFilePath,
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
  // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
  return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200>', tempFilePath]);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempFilePath);
  // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
  const thumbFileName = `thumb_${fileName}`;
  const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
  // Uploading the thumbnail.
  return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
    destination: thumbFilePath,
    metadata: metadata,
  });
  // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
}).then(() => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath));
```