# Error in Downloading files from GCS Storage bucket(not public access as important files cannot be made public)

Tags: python, flask, download, google-cloud-storage

If I set a specific path locally than using the localhost server(port=8080) it downloads the file but after deploying the app it shows path error. I understand after deployment it will be downloaded to a different path depending on remote machines. However what should be the path so any user can download the file to their local devices depending on their rights. FIles are pdf/txt etc. My bucket is not public. Should I give any sort of permissions or so?

Code using python Flask application.

```
def downloadfile():
  storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name = 'ABC'
    blob_name = request.form.get("name")
    url = request.form.get("url")
    #ur=url.split('/')[:-1]
    #delimiter='/'
    file = 'a1'
    bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob=bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_uri = '{}/{}'.format(ur, blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(url)

    return render_template("upload.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways that you can configure and give it a try, to set your application to an absolute path, to save the download of files locally.

This question from the Community - [Google Cloud storage library to read from Cloudstorage and download to local/on-prem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956950/google-cloud-storage-library-to-read-from-cloudstorage-and-download-to-local-on) - I believe provides the best example of how to achieve it (it's not on Python, but I believe you can follow the same logic for it) and code sample to set the absolute path.

Besides that, the below posts from the Community provides some additional information and examples on how to approach this.

- [How to set the destination for file.download() in Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195618/how-to-set-the-destination-for-file-download-in-google-cloud-storage)
- [Getting absolute filepath from Google Cloud Storage for use with pdf-text-extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866267/getting-absolute-filepath-from-google-cloud-storage-for-use-with-pdf-text-extrac)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: If, by using all the above links its still not working. I am able to download the file locally at this path - /home/dishti/Downloads/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python37/building-an-app/building-an-app-2/Downloads  CODE - 
    to_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('Downloads'))
    if not os.path.exists(to_dir):
       os.makedirs(to_dir)
    destination_path='{}/{}'.format(to_dir, blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_path)

Comment: But after deploying the app it shows path error and after printing the path its shows this - /home/vmagent/app/Downloads/a1.txt    but i cannot see the file. I am using virtual machine in windows does that effect?

Comment: Hi @theway indeed, it seems that the VM seems to be the problem, as per the path that it's being printed after the error. Could you please give it a try not using a VM?

Comment: What should be the path of a file to download it in a standard environment. And not giving a specific path to it. Just like in any browser anyone can download the file on clicking the download option to their downloads folder.? Can I not do that the same way?